# I wrote a stopwatch code, but this code is not running

Tags: javascript, html

This is a stopwatch code. But it is not running, I don't know where I made a mistake, I have posting the Html part will have heading, time section and three anchor tags. In JavaScript code I have written simple logic to execute the stopwatch program.

```
<div class="container">
      <h2>Stopwatch</h2>
      <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="*" id="play">play</a>
        <a href="*" id="pause">pause</a>
        <a href="*" id="reset">reset</a>
      </div>
  </div>

<script>
window.onload = function() {

let seconds = 00;
let tens = 00;

let appendSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
let appendTens = document.getElementById('tens');

let buttonStart = document.getElementById('play');
let buttonStop = document.getElementById('pause');
let buttonReset = document.getElementById('refresh');

let interval;

buttonStart.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
}

buttonStop.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

buttonReset.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    tens = "00";
    seconds = "00";
    appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
}


function startTimer () {
        tens++; 
       
        if (tens <= 9) {
          appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
        }
        
        if (tens > 9) {
          appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
          
        } 
        
        if (tens > 99) {
          console.log("seconds");
          seconds++;
          appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
          tens = 0;
          appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
        }
        
        if (seconds > 9) {
          appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
        }
       }
}
<\script>
```

This code is just loading for 2 - 3 seconds.

Comment: `<\script>` is incorrect. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. See [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does your browser's error console tell you anything useful?

Comment: @ Sebastian Simon What's Wrong ?

Comment: @NicoHaase ,When I click play(anchor tag) it just running for 2-3 seconds. No mam my browser's console was not showing any error

Comment: @PraveenKanth it should be `</script>` (wrong slash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Take a Look. **Is that what you are looking for .?** [See in action](https://codepen.io/eramudeep/pen/QWvGemK)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
 

    let seconds = 00;
    let tens = 00;

    let appendSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
    let appendTens = document.getElementById('tens');

    let buttonStart = document.getElementById('play');
    let buttonStop = document.getElementById('pause');
    let buttonReset = document.getElementById('refresh');

    let interval;

    buttonStart?.onclick = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
    }

    buttonStop?.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    buttonReset?.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(interval);
        tens = "00";
        seconds = "00";
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
        appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
    }


    function startTimer () {
            tens++; 
           
            if (tens <= 9) {
              appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
            }
            
            if (tens > 9) {
              appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
              
            } 
            
            if (tens > 99) {
              console.log("seconds");
              seconds++;
              appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
              tens = 0;
              appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
            }
            
            if (seconds > 9) {
              appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
            }
           }
     

  })
```

```css
.btn{
      padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h2>Stopwatch</h2>
      <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
      <div class="button">
        <a class="btn"  id="play">play</a>
        <a class="btn" id="pause">pause</a>
        <a  class="btn" id="reset">reset</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What have you changed, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent default for links, either to add in the link itself like:

`<a href="javascript:;" id="play">play</a>`

or to add in JS code like:

```
buttonStart.onclick = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       clearInterval(interval);
       interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
}
```

Also id of reset button was wrong

```
<a href="*" id="reset">reset</a>

let buttonReset = document.getElementById('reset');
```

Comment: Or, even better, make it a button that looks like a link.